Adding detail to a low-poly round object
I have the following model that has a curved bottom:

I would like to increase the number of vertices used on the curved edges to achieve a rounder look. How would I go about this?

Hello what does it give if you right click > Subdivide and in the Operator Box set the Smoothness to 1?

It works.. sort of. It only works with one subdivision. I then have to select all edges again, do subdivide again, etc. It's kind of a lot of work, but the results are okay. Thanks!

what does it give if you subdivide then right click > LoopTools > Relax? You need to activate the LoopTools addon first

I'd run a cleanup before you try @moonboot's suggestions. In Edit mode,use Mesh > Clean Up > Limited Dissolve which should get rid of most of the spurious edges that obviously weren't produced by Blender!

There are several solutions, you can right click > Subdivide and:

Right after the subdivide, in the Operator Box set the Smoothness to 1
Go into the Vertex panel on the top menu and Smooth Vertices and set the parameters in the Operator Box
Enable the LoopTools addon and right click > LoopTools > Relax then set the parameters in the Operator Box

